# Cannot pair Arc Touch mouse; too many unknown devices

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, microsoft-surface, wireless-mouse

A user wanted a wireless mouse for his Surface tablet. I grabbed a brand new and tested it by paring it with a brand new Surface tablet in the office and *did not unpair it*.

When I went to the user to pair the mouse, his Surface could not find it. It found 20-30 other unknown devices but no mention of the mouse right next to it unless it was one of the unknowns(??).

Does an Arc Touch mouse allow to be paired to multiple devices? Or were the unknowns an indicator of interference? Other Surface tablets in that office also showed 20-30 unknown devices in their scan and they couldn't find it either.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used my Microsoft Arc for a while so I forgot how to pair it and ended up with same issues like described here... it shows 20-30 unknown devices that cannot be paired.

Solution:
After I while i pressed and hold Bluetooth button next to the mouse sensor for five seconds after that device.

Comment: If you have a question just use Ask Question